# Spring MVC - bind enum array

Tags: spring-mvc, data-binding

If I post in the format `weather=sunny`, Spring MVC happily converts this to an Weather enum instance using the enum with name=sunny.

However if I post `weather=sunny&weather=windy`, then Spring is not able to convert it into an instance of Weather[]. The error I get is:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'com.blah.Weather[]' for property 'weather'
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Converter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/)s to perform the custom conversion. For your example, you would need to do something like:

```
public class WeatherConverter implements Converter<String[], Weather[]> {

    @Override
    public Weather[] convert(String[] source) {
        if(source == null || source.length == 0) {
            return new Weather[0];
        }
        Weather[] weathers = new Weather[source.length];
        int i = 0;
        for(String name : source) {
            weathers[i++] = Weather.valueOf(name); 
        }
        return weathers;
    }

}
```

You can use [Converter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/)s anywhere you might want type-conversions. Now, what you need to do is register it:

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="package.path.WeatherConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And it is done.

You can see more details in the [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert).

You could also look into [PropertyEditor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion)s, with [@InitBinder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html), and, probably, [@ControllerAdvice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) if you want. However, [Converters](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert) are much easier to use (IMO).